# Explicit formula for recurrence: T(n) = 2 * T(n - 1) + 4^n+1

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, recurrence

Can anyone please explain to me "how" I can obtain the explicit formula for the following recurrence?

- T(n) = 0 if n = 0
- T(n) = 2 * T(n - 1) + 4^n+1 if n > 0

Answer (score 1):

You do not need maple or anything else except of the old math.

So starting to unroll the recursion you get:

[image]

This recursion will exhaust when you reach `T(0)`, so when `k = n`. This will make the first element equal to 0, two next one are [geometric progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), for which you can calculate the sum.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Maple...

```
rsolve({t(0)=0, t(n)=2*t(n-1)+4^n+1}, t(n));
```

gives

```
-2^n-1+2*4^n
```

Now that you have the solution, you can try to prove it by induction.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert it to this formula for *n > 0*

[image]

if you analyze the sum you will see that it is

[image]

the first part (except -2^n) is a geometric progression, so we end up to this formula

[image]